# Sed: Add a word (or a new member) to a set line in a file

Tags: sed

Lets imagine I have a file with some lines and there is one line with this structure:

```
blah blah
YYYY      :['aaa','ddd']
blah
XXXX      :['member1', 'member2']
blah blah
```

I want to have a script to add member3 to the end of XXXX array automatically. I tried to use sed, but I do not know how to replace the last bracket of the lines started with XXXX with "'member3']". So it looks like this:

```
blah blah
YYYY      :['aaa','ddd']
blah
XXXX      :['member1', 'member2', 'member3']
blah blah
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed "/^XXXX /s/\]\$/, 'member3']/" < input
```

This applies a substitution to the lines that start with `XXXX`, replacing the final `]` with `'member3']`

Comment: thanks! I didn't know you could do the substitution like that! awesome!

Answer (score 0):

A bit unclear, is this what you're after:

```
$ echo "XXXXX      :['member1', 'member2']" | sed "s/]$/, 'member3']/"
XXXXX      :['member1', 'member2', 'member3']
```

**Update**

```
$ cat file.txt
bla
bla bla
XXXXX      :['member1', 'member2']
bla
bla bla

$ sed "s/]$/, 'member3']/" file.txt
bla
bla bla
XXXXX      :['member1', 'member2', 'member3']
bla
bla bla
```

Comment: No it is a file, I need to find the XXXX signature and then replace the last bracket with that string

Comment: please do. example before and after is always nice!